# replace a variable with a list of values

Tags: replacement

I have

```
VV = Table[RandomReal[{1, 7.}], {i, 1, 50}]
```

which  means I will have 20 values of vv

If `A=(e^2 +aa )/v^2;`

I want to  replace `v` by the first number in `vv` and calculate A then replace `v` by the second number in vv and calculate A and so on 
so how can I do the replacement ?

what I did before is this 
`A/A.V->vv` but it didn't work cause what i get was 20 set of `A` each set contain 20 numbers 
while what I want is one set of A with 20 numbers

Comment: You can use the `{}` button to format code on the website.

Comment: `A = (e^2 + aa)/VV^2` Note that you can also define `VV` as `VV = RandomReal[{1,7},  50];`, and the length is `50`, not `20`.

Answer (score 1):

Since you want a list with 20 elements, I suppose `e^2 + aa` isn't a list. In that case the following code should work:

```
VV = RandomReal[{1, 7}, 20]
A = (e^2 + aa)/v^2;
A /. v -> VV
```

> `{0.0526003 (aa + e^2), 0.0219029 (aa + e^2), 0.0301807 (aa + e^2), 
>    0.0236764 (aa + e^2), 0.069116 (aa + e^2), 0.0802288 (aa + e^2), 
>    0.139073 (aa + e^2), 0.0301545 (aa + e^2), 0.0399143 (aa + e^2), 
>    0.0340994 (aa + e^2), 0.0501276 (aa + e^2), 0.021865 (aa + e^2), 
>    0.0266181 (aa + e^2), 0.0453523 (aa + e^2), 0.0320551 (aa + e^2), 
>    0.0553022 (aa + e^2), 0.224468 (aa + e^2), 0.027523 (aa + e^2), 
>    0.673632 (aa + e^2), 0.0288074 (aa + e^2)}`

I fail to understand how you obtained a nested array, probably because `A/A.V->vv` is a typo.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe to avoid the problem of substituting a list for v directly, which may -- as Coolwater pointed out -- cause trouble it $e^2 + aa$ is a vector or matrix, using `Map` with a `List`of `Rule` might be more robust?

```
A = ( e^2 + aa ) / v^2;
vv = RandomReal[ { 1, 7 }, 20 ];
rules = Thread[ v -> vv ]; (* creates a list of replacement rules *)

Map[
    A /. # &,
    rules
]
```

> {0.0601751 (aa+e^2),0.28636 (aa+e^2),0.0361542 (aa+e^2),0.102103 (aa+e^2),0.104034 (aa+e^2),0.0547044 (aa+e^2),0.0986792 (aa+e^2),0.0615249 (aa+e^2),0.21111 (aa+e^2),0.0260811 (aa+e^2),0.170298 (aa+e^2),0.0324059 (aa+e^2),0.16291 (aa+e^2),0.560745 (aa+e^2),0.0391113 (aa+e^2),0.0859291 (aa+e^2),0.528882 (aa+e^2),0.0424362 (aa+e^2),0.0309525 (aa+e^2),0.115271 (aa+e^2)}